# attempt to call method 'insert' (a nil value) when i restart game

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I've added objects to the group so they get deleted and respawn when the game restarts but when the game restarts it gives the following error "attempt to call method 'insert' (a nil value)"

This is my object code:

```
local function spawnObject()
    local objIdx = mRandom(#objects)
    objName = objects[objIdx]

    object = display.newImage( "images/fruit_" .. objName .. "_100.png" )

    object.x = mRandom(screenLeft+30, screenRight-30)
    object.y = screenTop
    object.rotation = mRandom(-15, 15)
    object.id = mRandom(-15,15)

    group:insert( object )

    if objIdx < 4 then
        object.type = "food"
    else
        object.type = "other"
    end

    physics.addBody(object, "dynamic",{radius=45 , bounce = bt})
    grassfront320w:toFront()
    object.collision = objectCollision
    object:addEventListener( "collision", object )
end
```

And for restarting I go to restart scene which I've created and from there I go back to my play scene.

Please help me solve the problem.

Comment: Show us where you defined `group`

Comment: all of the above code is in the function i.e local function spawnObject() and I call this function in create scene so i guess its in the create scene group, I am sorry, I am new to this so i dont know a lot

Comment: Your error is pretty simple. You are trying to use `:insert` on `group` which is not defined (nil).

Comment: so how should i solve it?

Comment: ok solved it now i face another problem, the objects are spawning twice when i restart, i thought by adding them to group the previous spawning objects will be deleted but they did not.

Comment: You need to make sure it's the scenes group.

How are you "creating" the group? `local group = self.view`? You need to declare it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add directly to the `group` view. Make a separate display group for the objects

`local objectGroup = display.newGroup()
group:insert(objectGroup)`

by doing it this way, you are not obligated to kill out the group when you change scene (if you are using composer or storyboard). It will clear it self in the memory when you change scene.

Comment: hey @Jam i have did what u said but i still getting this error i go to previous scene and then i get back

Comment: Hmm, have you checked all of your object is in local scope? And to be safe clear all objects right after you change scene.